# Laravel on Google Compute Engine with Apache2 RewriteEngine on Returns 404

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, google-cloud-platform, apache2

I'm trying to host this website on google cloud using the compute engine and apache2. Since this is a previously established instance, there are a couple websites in there already and a pre configured .conf file as shown below. Uploading files and other stuffs are fine, and the website run smoothly, however i ran into the `/public` issue in where if the user didn't enter domain/public they'd be taken to the project directory index page instead.

i have tried creating the .htaccess file inside the laravel root directory, it got rid of the directory index page but it returns 404 instead. I have checked the routes are indeed listed and can be accessed with the `/public` even after the `RewriteEngine on` in .htaccess

lamp-server.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  <Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

404 :
[image: return 404 without public]

expected result : return the landing page

issue : server return 404 on existing routes without `/public` after .htaccess `RewriteEngine on`

question : How do i fix this so it doesnt return 404 without the `/public`?

attempt :

change RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]`

[image: edit 1]

Comment: Try using an absolute path `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]` . You also need to fix your your condition , `!^public` should be `!^/public` otherwise you might get a loop error

Comment: yessir i tried your suggestion, now its returning regular 404 not found instead of laravel's, will add details on the edit